# Simplifying $\sqrt{xy\mathstrut}\sqrt{x^3y}$ - two different paths, different results

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

I'm trying to simplify $\sqrt{xy\mathstrut}\sqrt{x^3y}$, for which the book has the solution below:

$$\sqrt{xy\phantom{\big|}}\sqrt{x^3y} = \sqrt{(xy)(x^3y)} = \sqrt{x^4y^2} = x^2|y|$$

I understand and agree with the above solution.  That said, prior to looking at the solution, I did the following, based on $\sqrt{ab} = \sqrt{a} \cdot \sqrt{b}$:

$$\sqrt{xy\phantom{\big|}}\sqrt{x^3y}$$
$$\sqrt{xy\phantom{\big|}}\sqrt{x\cdot y\cdot x^2}$$
$$\sqrt{xy\phantom{\big|}}\sqrt{xy\phantom{\big|}}\sqrt{x^2}$$
$$\sqrt{(xy)^2}\sqrt{x^2}$$
$$xy\sqrt{x^2}$$
$$xy|x|$$

Clearly, I'm getting a different/wrong answer.  I think I'm following the rules of radicals but am not getting the same result.

> What am I doing wrong?

Comment: $\sqrt{(xy)^2}=|xy|$ is your mistake, and $|x| \cdot |x|=x^2$ is how you simplify from there.

Comment: what about sqrt (X^4y^2)?

Comment: I believe $\sqrt(x^4y^2)$ would be $x^2|y|$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the stage where you simplify $\sqrt{(xy)^2}$ you should get $|xy|$, not $xy$. Therefore your final line should be $|xy||x|$, which is equal to $|x|^2 |y| = x^2 |y|$

Answer (score 4):

$$\sqrt{(xy)^2}\sqrt{(x^2)} = |xy|\sqrt{(x^2)} = |xy|\cdot |x| = |x|\cdot|y|\cdot |x| =  |x|^2\cdot|y| = x^2|y|$$

Answer (score 2):

The previous answers are right, but it may be of interest that your answer, though incorrectly arrived at, is in fact correct.  The expression makes no sense unless $x$ and $y$ have the same sign, and then your answer is equivalent to the one in the book.